# Urbanairship PushNotification in BB Issue , not getting Pushnotification

Tags: java, android, blackberry, urbanairship.com

I am working on Push-notification Application. I got a demo from [UrbanAirship](https://github.com/urbanairship/bb-push-sample-os5) & I got credentials from BB Push service. I have created an account on UrbanAirhip.

I have configured Blackbery Account in Urbanairship , It's asking for credential & **Pushurl**.

here are the credentials list which I got from BB Push Service

App ID: 3XXX-917XXX1317tr8o5714m4MXXXX2l7ak05hB3
 Pwd: smnBI789
 CPID (Content Provider ID): 0
 PPG Base URL http ://cp(Your AppId).pushapi.eval.blackberry.com
 Usage:BIS
 Service Type:Essentials

I am passing  http://cp3XXX-917XXX1317tr8o5714m4MXXXX2l7ak05hB3.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com
if i try to save url(**Pushurl**) with Prefix HTTP then its not work , however if i am save the URL with HTTPS its work.

I have Integrated it in Application and when I run app,it will give me Success(200 code).
but here is problem raise with pushnotification,I am not getting any Test push when I send from Urban Airship account ..

May be any kind of setting for the pushNotification or its a BIS plan issue.
Please suggest me on same.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you successfully registered to receive `Push Messages` in your device? Successful registration returns an `rc=200` code in the client app, i.e your device with an active BIS connection and Wi-Fi tured off.

Comment: I turned off the device Wifi Connection and tried to Open UrbanAirship Demo ..it give me Status 200

Comment: So now you are successfully registered to receive `Push Message`. Try sending the message now with the `URL` amended as mentioned by @WilliamSun below.

Comment: just one query ..What is the correct pushURl, when we configure UrbanAirship BB account  a)https://cp3XXX-917XXX1317tr8o5714m4MXXXX2l7ak05hB3.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com       b)https://cp3XXX.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com

Comment: The correct URL to push message is : 
`String httpURL = "https://cpxxxx.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest";`
I have not worked with UrbanAirship so cannot comment specifically to it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the base URL for the PPG, your Push Initiator uses the BlackBerry Internet Service (BIS) and the Push Initiator is called a PUBLIC_PUSH type of Push Initiator.  PPG for PUBLIC_PUSH type of Push Initiator uses `https://cp<cpid>.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com` URL as the public.ppg.address property thus replacing the ${ppg.base.url} token.

The PPG for ENTERPRISE_PUSH or BDS_PUSH type of Push Initiator that uses BlackBerry Enterprise Server or BlackBerry Device Service respectively, requires host name and port number of the BlackBerry MDS Connection Service in the format of `http://<host name>:port number (eg. http://server:7000)`for the enterprise.ppg.address or bds.ppg.address properties

Presuming you specified that you registered for the Push Essential package and that you are not receiving Test Push Notifications, there could be a multiple of issues.  Did you verify that your BB Username/Application ID, Password, URL, device PIN, is all correct?  Receiving 200 code seems like the message was not correctly surfaced.  Did you specify the content-type that you expect the client-side application to receive?

Comment: thanks @William Sun ..for the answer ..I am just want to know is my UrbanAirship BB account configuration setting is correct or  ..I have to configure again